# Werid behaviour of IIS 6

Tags: iis-7, iis-6, iis

I have a site who needs to be pointed to: `inetpub\wwwroot\cakephp\app\webroot\`

If I point the "**Default Web Site**" to that directoy, my web application works perfectly.

Now, as I want to add more sites to that same computer, I am pointing the "**Default Web Site**" to `inetpub\wwwroot\` and the concrete folder for my web application to the previous path `inetpub\wwwroot\cakephp\app\webroot\`.

When I do this I have noticed it doesn't even execute the index.php file located inside `inetpub\wwwroot\cakephp\app\webroot\` contrary as it should. It only does it when accessing directly to the root of the site.

To clarify it:

- `www.myweb.com/cakephp/` executes `inetpub\wwwroot\cakephp\app\webroot\index.php`
- `www.myweb.com/cakephp/actionName/` does **NOT** executes `inetpub\wwwroot\cakephp\app\webroot\index.php`

Why is this happening? Why it doesn't recognize the given path when I add any parameter to the URL? 
It tries to list the folder content instead...

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Things to check: Does the application have the correct execution settings? Is the default document set? Is the .php extension in the handler mappings?

Comment: The .php extension is added and the default document enabled. Plus it works well when I navigate to the root  site folder as I said. The web site folder has "Script source access", "Read" and "Write" (configured inside Properties/Virtual Directory).